# Python run a shell script with ksh environment and setent.sh

Tags: python, shell, ksh, setenv

I am trying to change a shell scrip to a python script to enable a multiprocessing feature.

The current shell script is

```
#! /bin/ksh
. /sys/etc/setenv.sh

/my/program.X parameter1 2016-08-01@00:10 2016-08-01@00:20 2 >> /my/data/20160801.log | gzip - > /my/data/20160801.0010.1h.dat.gz
```

I have tried to use python subprocess, but cannot figure out the exact way to run this script.

setenv.sh is pretty large and complicated script, I need to run it as is under ksh, then need to run the program.

Comment: can you write this content to a file and then pass the name of this file to `/bin/ksh` via `subprocess`?

Comment: Whatever `setenv.sh` does, you need to translate it to Python as well; otherwise, there's little point in doing anything other than simply calling `os.system("script.sh")`.

Comment: I believe that will work, but I would rather like to find a better (neat) way to run it. Thanks for your comment anyway.